# How to implement conditional colors on a time series plot in Altair

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I've got a dataset that I'm trying to work up around hospital admissions over time.

Here's the python

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
pd.options.display.max_columns = 10
pd.options.display.max_rows = 50
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
alt.data_transformers.disable_max_rows()
df = pd.read_csv("sorted_data.csv")
```

## The data is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Uvaq93-pMYSUgXbq2N2WAgtWn8t2Tbn2/view?usp=sharing

```
# Create dropdown for Major region
major_region_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=df['Major region'].unique().tolist(), name="Major region: ")
major_region_selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['Major region'], bind=major_region_dropdown) #, value={"Major region": "Major region"}

# Create dropdown for variable
variable_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=df['variable'].unique().tolist(), name="Category: ")
variable_selection = alt.selection_point(fields=['variable'], bind=variable_dropdown) #, value={"variable": "Total admissions"} Removed because broke code


# Main chart
main_chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(point=True).encode(
    x='Year:O',
    y='mean(quantity):Q',
    color=alt.Color('Region:N', legend=None),  # Set legend to None
    tooltip=["Major region", "Region", "mean(quantity):Q"]
).add_params(
    major_region_selection
).transform_filter(
    major_region_selection
).add_params(
    variable_selection
).transform_filter(
    variable_selection
).properties(
    width=450, 
    height=600,
    title="Region")
main_chart
```

[image]

The first problem with the chart is that although the Major Region selector defaults to 'North West', it displays every line which is confusing. Oddly, you can select another region and it settles down.

The second problem is that there are often too many minor regions to make out trends. Take this for the Major region of London.

[image]

There are too many sub-regions to list in a legend so instead I'd like to have every line in light grey and then turn red when one of the points is selected. . Ideally, i'd like to have selection on an individual.

How do I put that condition into place. I know it's under the color attribute, but I can't work it out.

HERE'S the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Pw2wfr82laHXw7KKqp-nXeJt2cjwtZC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example of your input data

Comment: You can achieve this by using a combination of **alt.condition**, **alt.Color**, and **alt.selection** with the nearest parameter.